# All ASPNET Core routes to go to DefaultFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want all requests apart from `/api/*` to hit the default file in the wwwroot folder because I'm running a spa!

I have this configured:

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = identityServerAppOptions.Value.Authority,
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

    ApiName = "all",

});
app.UseDefaultFiles(new DefaultFilesOptions
{
    DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index.html" }
});
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
    {
        ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    }
});
app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "api/{controller=Details}/{id?}"));
```

But it doesn't route `/Account/Login` to the default file from the static file location.

I've tried using `RequestPath` on the static files options but that doesn't sound like the right thing anyway!

Comment: do you have files like wwwroot/Account/Login/index.html on disk?

Comment: no all files are in `wwwroot` in the structure intended to serve a SPA app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to selectively rewrite a request URL to `/index.html` using [URL Rewriting Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting) and regular expressions.

To skip all requests starting with `/api/*` use regexp:   `@"^(?!api/).*$"`

To skip all requests starting with `/api/*` and all requests containing a dot `.`:  `@"^(?!api/|.*\..*).*$"`

```
var options = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^(?!api/|.*\..*).*$", "index.html", true);
app.UseRewriter(options);

//should be after a rewriter in middleware pipeline
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

P.S. Regular expressions can by optimized, I guess. But the concept is the same.

Comment: this doesn't accept file requests, so `vendor.js` will get rewritten to `index.html`

Comment: I just did `^\/(?!api/).*$` instead

Comment: I need one which doesn't rewrite URLs that end in a file extension

Comment: @CallumLinington, let's try to exclude any string with dot. `@"^(?!api/|.*\..*).*$"`